# How do I create a rule that will fire only on my site's home page?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I using Google Tag Manager and I am trying to setup a rule that will fire ONLY on my sites homepage.

The issue is that I am not certain how to handle all of the URL permutations of the homepage. How can I create a rule that will handle:

```
"http://" "https://" "http://www." "https://www."
```

Also, we use Sitecore and support multiple languages, so the homepage url can also display as:

```
"http://www.mysite.com/en"
```

I am not sure how to handle the culture identifier that is inserted into the URL path after a visitor has used the navigation on the site.

Is it possible to use the OOTB Google Tag Manager rules to handle this scenario, or will I have to implement a Tag Manager Data Layer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following rule would check if it's the homepage:

### `{{url}}` matches RegEx `^https?://(www\.)?mysite\.com/?(index\.html)?$`

`{{url}}` gives the whole address whereas `{{url domain}}` just gives the domain and `{{url path}}` just the path (including the initial forward slash).

This matches `http` and `https`, with or without `www` and with or without `index.html` at the end. It also matches `mysite.com/` and `mysite.com` (without the forward slash at the end). If you want to check for URL permutations at the end of the homepage, you could do something like:

`^https?://(www\.)?mysite\.com/?(en|es|fr)?$` etc.

Also, forward slashes do NOT have to be escaped. In fact, escaping forward slashes broke the firing rule in GTM for me...

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

edit: and if you want to ignore the querystring (which is a good thing to do because most ads add query keys such as `utm_source` etc. to the url), you can have something like this:

```
^https?://(www\.)?mysite\.com/?(index\.html)?/?(\?.*)?$
```

(note the `(\?.*)?` at the end)

Comment: Nice work Erfan. I was able to consolidate four rules into one!

Comment: What about anchors with #

Answer (score 3):

Ok... so after researching the Google Tag Manager Forum, this can be accomplished by making separate url "ends with" rules for your site url and then your site url with a trailing forward slash such as:

```
rule 1 : url ends with http://mysite.com

rule 2 : url ends with http://mysite.com/
```

I think it was the trailing slash that was confusing the matter as I was setting up the rules.

Answer (score 3):

This is a super robust way to know it's your home page with either protocol and allow for a backslash all with one line of Regex...

```
^https?://www.mydomain\.com\/?$
```

Not sure sure why the initial double backslashes don't have to be escaped, but it works. Would have expected `^https?:\/\/www.mydomain\.com\/?$` Maybe someone else knows that :)

Comment: Works like a charm, even with query string parameters on it.

Comment: Interesting. The $ should signal end.

Comment: @doublejosh 
It depends on the bot.

Bots that follow the `robots.txt` specification don’t give the `*` any special meaning. These bots would block any URL whose path starts with `/*`, directly followed by `?`. So, `?` is essentially wildchar(s) until `$` if i understood this correctly.