# Google Tag Manager to trigger on site homepage, including when UTM is present

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

Subject: Google Tag Manager trigger for homepage only with UTM parameters

Hi,
I’m trying to show a chat widget on my website’s homepage. I currently have a GTM trigger for the homepage:

Page Path
I found that solution here: [How do I create a rule that will fire only on my site's home page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575145/how-do-i-create-a-rule-that-will-fire-only-on-my-sites-home-page)
 [Fire GTM tag only if on homepage of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430564/fire-gtm-tag-only-if-on-homepage-of-the-site)

However, this doesn’t appear if there are UTM parameters after the home page. For example:
https://www.example.com/?utm_source=linkedin&utm_medium=paid%2Bsocial&utm_campaign=example-campaign

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

You should create variables for the UTM like this:

[image: UTM source variable creation]

And then from the trigger do something like this:

[image: Trigger configuration example]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am not sure this is what the OP wants - I think he wants to fire the page no matter if parameters are present or not. Your solution only fires when the parameter is present and has a specific value.

Comment: @EikePierstorff ohh ok, i may misunderstood this. In any case using a regex isnt the best idea he should be better of just using the second part of my solution (matching by page path equals '/') and thats it.

Comment: @Marco Matching by page path = / doesn't solve the UTM problem because once there are UTM variables, it's not an exact match

Comment: @avi Yes because the Page Path does not include the parameters of the URL.